# Regular Expression matches returns false

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am using this regular expression:

```
String regex = '(\\d{11}|\\d{5} \\d{6}|\\+\\d{12})';

Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher match = compiledPattern.matcher('Inbound Call at 5:10:54 PM from 07970123123 (Jack Daniels)');

if (match.matches()) {
    System.debug('MATCH');
    String phone = match.group(1);
} else {
    System.debug('MISS');
}
```

To extract the phone number from this String:

> Inbound Call at 5:10:54 PM from 07970123123 (Jack Daniels)

When I test the Regex in:

- [Java Regular Expression Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html)
- [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

It works fine.

But when I try and use it in Apex code, it does not find a match.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation on the Matcher class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) should shed some light here.

The description for `matches()` states the following

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

Meanwhile the description for `find()` is

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. This method returns true if a subsequence of the input sequence matches this Matcher object's pattern.

`find()` is what you want to use here, since you want to match a *portion* of the input.

An example for illustration

```
String regex = '(\\d{11}|\\d{5} \\d{6}|\\+\\d{12})';
Pattern msgPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m1 = msgPattern.matcher('Inbound Call at 5:10:54 PM from 07970123123 (Jack Daniels)');

system.debug(m1.matches()); // displays false
system.debug(m1.find()); // displays true
```

Answer (score 7):

It does work - but only if you use the method that yields a substring match.

```
String input = 'Inbound Call at 5:10:54 PM from 07970123123 (Jack Daniels)';
String regex = '(\\d{11}|\\d{5} \\d{6}|\\+\\d{12})';

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

System.debug('Find: ' + m.find()); // true
System.debug('Group: ' + m.group()); // 07970123123
System.debug('Matches: ' + m.matches()); // false
```

`Matcher.matches()` asks to find a match against the entire input region. `Matcher.find()` locates a group *within* the input region.